# within a sql while loop, get id of last inserted row then insert it into a different table, using OUTPUT?

Tags: sql

I am writing some sql, using sql server 2008, to loop around some records. Within this loop I need to insert a row and the ID of that row will be put into a field in an existing record in a different table. I thought I would be able to achieve this with OUTPUT but I couldn't find an example of exactly what I wanted to do.

Here's what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @courseTempID INT
DECLARE @courseID INT
DECLARE @academicYearID INT
DECLARE @courseCode VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @uio_id INT
DECLARE @creatorIntranetUserID INT

WHILE (SELECT count(*) FROM CoursesTemp WHERE dmprocessed = 0) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @id = courseTempID FROM CoursesTemp WHERE dmprocessed = 0
    SELECT TOP 1 @academicYearID = academicYearID FROM CoursesTemp WHERE dmprocessed = 0
    SELECT TOP 1 @courseCode = courseCode FROM CoursesTemp WHERE dmprocessed = 0
    SELECT TOP 1 @uio_id = uio_id FROM CoursesTemp WHERE dmprocessed = 0
    SELECT TOP 1 @creatorIntranetUserID = creatorIntranetUserID FROM CoursesTemp WHERE dmprocessed = 0

    INSERT INTO dbo.Courses VALUES(3,@academicYearID,1,@courseCode,@uio_id,GETDATE(),@creatorIntranetUserID)

    OUTPUT INSERTED.courseID INTO @courseID 

    UPDATE CoursesTemp SET dmprocessed = 1, courseID = @courseID WHERE courseTempID = @courseTempID

END
```

The error I am getting is "Incorrect syntax near 'INSERTED'".

Can anyone help me work out how to use OUTPUT in this way please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few performance improvements applied. It is safer to use SCOPE_IDENTITY()

```
DECLARE @courseTempID INT
DECLARE @courseID INT
DECLARE @academicYearID INT
DECLARE @courseCode VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @uio_id INT
DECLARE @creatorIntranetUserID INT
DECLARE @id INT

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CoursesTemp WHERE dmprocessed = 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @id = courseTempID 
        ,@academicYearID = academicYearID
        ,@courseCode = courseCode
        ,@uio_id = uio_id
        ,@creatorIntranetUserID = creatorIntranetUserID 
    FROM CoursesTemp WHERE dmprocessed = 0

    INSERT INTO dbo.Courses VALUES(3,@academicYearID,1,@courseCode,@uio_id,GETDATE(),@creatorIntranetUserID)
    UPDATE CoursesTemp SET dmprocessed = 1, courseID = SCOPE_IDENTITY() WHERE courseTempID = @courseTempID
END
```

Comment: This is the right solution but there is a tiny error, it would fail with an error message saying you must declare the variable "@id", this should be changed to "@courseTempID."

Comment: @GarethD: you are right, I didn't pay attention to variable declaration assuming it was done correctly in original query

Comment: @Tomek this works perfectly. I didn't know you could use SCOPE_IDENTITY() this way, I always thought it had to be at the end of an INSERT statement which is assigned to a variable. Thanks for this, it will be really useful to know for future projects.

Answer (score 1):

`OUTPUT` needs to go between `INSERT INTO dbo.Courses` and `VALUES(...)`
You also have `OUTPUT INSERTED.courseID INTO @CourseId` but @CourseId is an int variable, it needs to be the table you want to insert into.

**EDIT** I've reread what you're tying to do.  Instead of using `OUTPUT`, you can change your last line to

```
UPDATE CoursesTemp SET dmprocessed = 1, courseId = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
WHERE courseTempID = @courseTempID
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use @@IDENTITY to retrieve the last-inserted ID value. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx